# jQuery delegate() / on() - force order of events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Perhaps a silly question  but...

In this simple code:

```
 $(".Q").on("click", ".container", containerClick);
 $(".Q").on("click", ".container .oneElement", oneElementInContainerClicked);
```

if `.oneElement` in `.container` is clicked, first `oneElementInContainerClicked` is called.

Is is possible to force the order of events such that `containerClick` is called first, then `oneElementInContainerClicked`?

Comment: _"Is is possible to force the order of events such that containerClick is called first, then oneElementInContainerClicked"_ Is expected result for both click handlers to be called ?

Comment: One approach could be to manually invoke `containerClick` (or the logic that *it* invokes, preferably) from within `oneElementInContainerClicked` in the order that you want, and then stop the event propagation for the other handler isn't called.

Comment: That concept is called event capturing..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249125/event-capturing-jquery

Comment: thank you all, yes, I know i can do that (manually call the other event), but was wondering if there was another way. it seems like there is not

Comment: That's default event bubbling behaviour. Why would you want to change that? What is the problem you are facing with the order?

Comment: @bergi because it would allow me to change some functionality without touching the contents of both event handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including check for `e.target` within `containerClick` ; calling `.trigger("click")` on `$(this).parents(".container")` within `oneElementInContainerClicked`

```js
function containerClick(e) {
  if (e.target.className !== "oneElement")
    console.log("container")
} 

function oneElementInContainerClicked() {
  console.log("oneElement");
  $(this).parents(".container").trigger("click")
} 


$(".Q").on("click", ".container", containerClick);
 $(".Q").on("click", ".container .oneElement", oneElementInContainerClicked);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="Q">
  <div class="container">container
    <div class="oneElement">oneElement</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @GregBala Note, while re-reading Question, appear that `$(this).parents(".container").trigger("click")` should be called before `console.log("oneElement");` within `oneElementInContainerClicked` to return expected results ?